# PhpStorm using too much RAM when using angular cli

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm

I was trying to test [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). When I do `npm start` in my terminal, everything is ok. but after some time, my PhpStorm gets really slow and indexing all the time, and I always have to wait like a minute~ until I can type again, which is impossible to program like that. My phpStorm takes up to 1gb RAM (!) which clearly never happens. My PhpStorm version is 2016.1.2.

---

### System Information

```
  Time of this report: 6/12/2016, 23:17:17
         Machine name: DESKTOP-092KPIB
     Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 10586) (10586.th2_release_sec.160422-1850)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
         System Model: X555LJ
                 BIOS: BIOS Date: 08/04/15 10:57:50 Ver: 05.0000A
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.4GHz
               Memory: 8192MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 8092MB RAM
            Page File: 5222MB used, 6453MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
      DirectX Version: 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
   System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
             Miracast: Available, with HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Supported
       DxDiag Version: 10.00.10586.0000 64bit Unicode
```

Is it a problem in my PC?

**Update**:

I've just noticed that I have 10 processes running. I opened them and this is what I saw:
https://gyazo.com/b309e5b4e790faec5a0a495c28224f3a

this is my SCSS Watcher:
https://gyazo.com/0bce683f60ad9ae75d30b770f823225b

I don't know why, but I can't stop those tasks. This issue didn't happen to me before, so I know it's not the main reason why phpStorm gets stucky.

Comment: it's always eating way too much ram.

Comment: @MikeKor There has to be another way. It's impossible to program like that.

Comment: Your comp is slowing down because it's swapping memory on hard disk. Get more ram or don't use phpstorm.

Answer (score 0):

I have 4th gen Intel i5, 1 TB SSHD, 6 GB of RAM and PhpStorm loads slow, glitches sometimes but most of the time is working fine and I'm satisfied with it. Reason why is sometimes slow is that is written in Java and almost everything made with Java is slow.

So, to answer your question, it's not your computer, it's JRE that works slow and eats a lot of RAM.

In my case, PhpStorm uses in average 0.5 GB of RAM with few small files opened...

EDIT: If you want to improve performance, replacing your HDD with SSD will make everything faster ;)

EDIT 2: In case someone ends up here with similar symptoms, check out this link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1026

Comment: When you go to task manager or process explorer, is phpStorm only one "heavy"? 
You have better configuration than I do, only major difference is that I have win8.1 professional

Comment: It looks like you're not the only one having performance issues... I just googled out this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1026